# didSelectRowAtIndexPath only called on first three rows

Tags: xcode, ios5, didselectrowatindexpath

I am using didSelectRowAtIndexPath in xcode 4.2 on iOS 5.0

It works fine *for the first 3 rows of the table* but is not called on the forth or subsequent ones. My evidence that it is not called is an NSLog entry in the method: touching rows 1,2 or 3 spits out a log but touch row 4,5 and up, no log.

I assume that, since it works for the first three rows, I must have the delegate stuff plugged correctly.  All the rows *look* the same, and if I rearrange the data the problem stays with the forth and higher rows, so doesn't look like a data issue.

Not enabled editing.

Comment: So, yeah, answering your question is impossible if you do not provide any code. Either show the relevant parts inline in this post, or past the full classes in gist or something :)

Comment: and `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is not implemented?